# Access Denied for MySql Error

Tags: mysql

When I try to login into my MySql Server in Ubuntu 14.04 I got the following 
Error

### Error

mca@mca-acer-162:~$ mysql --user=root --password
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

I haven't set any password.  So, I keep it null

How to Rectify it?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: try to improve your question by adding some line of your code.

Comment: to start with, remove the `=` after password. You should not specify the password there, you'll get a prompt to enter it if you just specify `--password`. Check also if mysql service is running : `ps aux | grep mysql`. Try that and post what happens.

Comment: Thomas G,I have tried by removing the = after the --password and also checked the status of MySql also it's already running.

Comment: I have removed the java and jdbc tags, as they are irrelevant for your question, which seems to be about connecting to MySQL itself using the MySQL CLI tool.

Comment: Run `lsof -i :3306` to check that the server is running and listening to that port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not set any passwort, why do you use the --password flag?

Just try *mysql --user=root*

Comment: I have already tried without using the password flag but it results the same error I have mentioned above.

Comment: Then are you sure there is no password? I think if you install mysql in ubuntu you are asked for a root password. Otherwise this should work if no password is set.